# SuperSet Python intergration with R ( rpy2)

Tags: python, rpy2, apache-superset

Since the majority of our Data Science application work is on Python (flask) and R ( using rpy2) and Tornado web-server, is there any possibility I can integrate my current python code / application in Superset?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your specific requirements for integrating your existing logic into Superset - but Superset is essentially a python Flask app.

As such, you could extend it and incorporate whatever python modules you've already built.

In particular, you could extend/implement your own visualization (see https://superset.incubator.apache.org/faq.html#how-do-i-create-my-own-visualization) and could even conceivably create your own type of datasources (cf. `BaseDatasource`, `DruidDatasource`, and `SqlaTable`).